# Sort List<List<Integer>> based on the Integer in the second index of the inner List<Integer>?

Tags: java

Imagine I have the following input:

```
[[5,3,6,7],[2,1,6,3],[3,2,6,3],[5,4,4,3]]
```

How could I sort it based on the second number of each list, so that I have the following: (because 1 < 2 < 3 < 4)

```
[[2,1,6,3],[3,2,6,3],[5,3,6,7],[5,4,4,3]]
```

I imagine you can do something with Streams, but I haven't quite figured it out.

Comment: Show us what you've tried so far. A good start is to try to describe in plain text what defines order of those elements.

Comment: Why don't you just write a simple comparator to handle this?

Comment: `I imagine you can do something with Streams` what a crazy idea!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, this is very simple. Actually you can look at list sorting and custom comparator.

```
public static void sortBySecondIndex(List<List<Integer>> data) {
    data.sort(Comparator.comparingInt(one -> one.get(1)));        
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
list.sort((a, b) -> a.get(1).compareTo(b.get(1)));
```